# JavaScript button click not executing fast enough

Tags: javascript, html, css, hover

Look following example. Click on reset button, you will get console log 1 so you can confirm its working.

When you click search field, it will expand, making buttons float to new line (including reset button). Now if you try to click reset button while its in new line, the transition which closes search field will execute faster than the click on the reset button. Not a major problem but intriguing. Is this expected behavior?

```js
document.querySelector(".reset").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  console.log(1)
});
```

```css
.wrap {
  max-width: 700px;
}

.a {
  padding: 10px 50px;
  background: #ccc;
  display: inline-flex;
}

.filter {
  width: 50px;
  transition: all 0.1s;
}

.filter:focus {
  width: 250px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <input type="search" class="filter">
  <div class="a">button 1</div>
  <div class="a">button 2 </div>
  <div class="a">button 3</div>
  <div class="a reset">reset</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes. Because the click event is fired after you have blurred/unfocused from the `.filter` element.

Comment: There are a lot of [mouse events](https://www.w3.org/TR/uievents/#events-mouse-types) and [touch events](https://www.w3.org/TR/touch-events/#list-of-touchevent-types) available for you to use. In your case, use `mousedown` as @Danny answer is recommended.

Answer (score 3):

I think the issue is that the `blur` event is firing before the `click` event occurs, to remedy this you can use the `mousedown` event which fires before `blur`:

```
document.querySelector(".reset").addEventListener("mousedown", function(e) {
  console.log(1)
});
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/b4opezq3/ Work.

Answer (score 0):

`onclick` requires the events `onmousedown` and `onmouseup` to be concurrent.

In your case, they are separated by the `focusout` event, and so `onclick` doesn't fire.

https://w3c.github.io/uievents/#click

> Depending upon the environment configuration, the click event MAY be dispatched if one or more of the event types mouseover, mousemove, and mouseout occur between the press and release of the pointing device button.